# automatic recrawl sites in nutch 1.4?

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I want to recrawl my sites 3 times a day. I know I should write a script for this but i don't know how? and i don't know how run the script ?
can someone explain this step by step
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script. Below structure can be used:

1. while loop
2. ......command which u use to invoke nutch once
3. ......sleep for few hours
4. end loop

Run this script using nohup or screen session. It will work great !!